# I have tried installing Mifos X on Xampp. It's worked as I could access the UI on my browser but I had lots of problems with the credentials

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb, mifos

I recently installed Mifos X on my laptop on Windows 10 Pro using the Xampp server.
I put the fineract folder in the htdocs as I would with all the other framework. Only problem, after following all the steps, I was using mariaDB server and I set the password differently from the one they suggested (note: I followed all the instructions only changed the MySQL Server pword differently and was using pma as workbench).
I would like some assistance on how to fix the credential problems as well as being able to set up the incubator-fineract for developers.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the war file inside the tomcat webapps directory and I strongly suggest that you use the pre-defined username and password for mysql connection , if you like in production you can do this so by editing this file

```
https://github.com/apache/fineract/blob/develop/fineract-provider/src/main/java/org/apache/fineract/infrastructure/core/boot/db/DataSourceProperties.java
```

Apache Fineract uses self singed certificate , one has to open the https://localhost:8443/fineract-provider/

You will see the screen to accept and store the certificate in your browser and then you can login via your UI.

Comment: I did that. All the time I do that. 
I have decided to leave xampp and installed all the features on their own and following the exact same instructions. The Mifos X UI gets displayed but I get the following error: Couldn't connect to server. Make sure you are using correct settings.

What can I do to fix it? 
keystorePath: C:/Users/[UserName]/.keystore
keystorePass: *****

mysql -u root -p mysql

These are the current credentials I am using.

Comment: You mean keystone, username and password or mysql username and password .

Comment: I think I have figured was wrong in all the process.
Everything is related to the Tomcat server.
I have been doing the exact same way as the installation guide suggested but it never worked. Only when I used Apache Tomcat or XAMPP that I could at least access to the UI.
What precisely could be a way to solve the problem with the server?